# How to find the equivalent Linq command for translated SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table with `Guid` as a primary key and multiple `nvarchar(max)` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tables](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Id] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

And

```
public partial class Table : INamedEntity, IEntityKey<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private Table() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

which is translated to this query in `SQL Server`:

```
    SELECT   [Id], DATALENGTH([Description]), [Description] , DATALENGTH([Name]), [Name] 
    FROM     [dbo].[Table]
    WHERE    [Id] < @UpperBound
    ORDER BY [Id] ASC
```

I have the same problem with another table with

```
public class Document : IEntityKey<Guid>
{
    public Document() { }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
(@UpperBound uniqueidentifier)
SELECT   [Id],  CASE WHEN DATALENGTH([Data]) >= 4116480 THEN DATALENGTH(0x2142494E5F46494C45213A + CAST (CAST (newid() AS VARCHAR (100)) AS VARBINARY (100))) ELSE DATALENGTH([Data]) END, CASE WHEN DATALENGTH([Data]) >= 4116480 THEN 0x2142494E5F46494C45213A + CAST (CAST (newid() AS VARCHAR (100)) AS VARBINARY (100)) ELSE [Data] END, [Name],[Extension]  FROM [dbo].[Documents]  
    WHERE    [Id] < @UpperBound 
    ORDER BY [Id] ASC
```

As you can see `Data` column is weird in the translated query.
These queries are slow and I should tune them but I can not find the their origins in `C#` code. Therefore I am looking for an equivalent translated `Linq` command. Would you please guide me about:

1. What is the equivalent `Linq`?
2. Why is `nvarchar(max)` translated to two columns `DATALENGTH([Description]), 
   [Description]`?
3. Why is `byte[]` translated to `CASE WHEN DATALENGTH([Data]) >= 4116480 THEN DATALENGTH(0x2142494E5F46494C45213A + CAST (CAST (newid() AS VARCHAR (100)) AS VARBINARY (100))) ELSE DATALENGTH([Data]) END,           CASE WHEN DATALENGTH([Data]) >= 4116480 THEN 0x2142494E5F46494C45213A + CAST (CAST (newid() AS VARCHAR (100)) AS VARBINARY (100)) ELSE [Data] END`?

Comment: In your POCO's configurations, are you telling EF that the fields are of type NVARCHAR? If you don't, EF might try to do some weird conversions behind the scenes.

The reason for the split is because EF needs the length information.

Comment: Update your question with full table definition schema and full query (without `...`!) and also related POCO

Answer (score 1):

In our environment, we also saw a similar strange and slow query with the same weird constant `0x2142494E5F46494C45213A`. It was caused by a Data-tier Application Package (DACPAC) export. Even better was that canceling the job didn't kill the query, but killing SSMS stopped it.